# Ms Access query not working. Please suggest

Tags: ms-access, vba

[image][image]Help needed for the below query. Thanks

```
SELECT b.SchemeCode_Db,
    'DBELE',
    1,
    SecurityCode_Db,
    "DIRECT",
    Qty,
    Price,
    ((Commission + TransferCharge) / Qty) AS Charges,
    "",
    iif(Buy_sell_code = "1110", 
            ((Qty * Price) + Commission + TransferCharge),
            iif(Buy_sell_code = "1120", ((Qty * Price) - Commission 
                    - TransferCharge
                ))) AS totalCost,
    BrokerCode_Db,
    "",
    Deal,
    Format(Tradedate, "dd/MM/yyyy"),
    Format(Valuedate, "dd/MM/yyyy"),
    '', 'BSE', 'CH', 'D', '',
    iif(Buy_sell_code = "1110", 
            'PUR', 
            iif(Buy_sell_code = "1120", 'SAL')) AS txn,
    'USD' AS cur
FROM tbl_EQUITYINPUT a
LEFT JOIN tbl_EQUITYMapping b
    ON FundCode = SchemeCode_Client
LEFT JOIN tbl_EQUITYMapping c
    ON Ticker = SecurityCode_Client
LEFT JOIN tbl_EQUITYMapping d
    ON Broker = Brokercode_Client
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Access db engine requires parentheses in the `FROM` clause when your query includes more than one `JOIN`.  I suspect this `FROM` clause version will be a step closer to something the db engine will accept.

```sql
FROM
    ((tbl_EQUITYINPUT a
    LEFT JOIN tbl_EQUITYMapping b
        ON FundCode = SchemeCode_Client)
    LEFT JOIN tbl_EQUITYMapping c
        ON Ticker = SecurityCode_Client)
    LEFT JOIN tbl_EQUITYMapping d
        ON Broker = Brokercode_Client
```

However, I'm uncertain whether the db engine will be confused sorting out which join field comes from which table source.   I would prefix those field names with the proper table alias.

But I think your most direct route to joy for this may be to start with a new query in Design View in the query designer.  Add `tbl_EQUITYINPUT` and 3 copies of `tbl_EQUITYMapping` and assign the aliases.  Then set up your joins between them while still in Design View.  The query designer understands the join rules which keep the engine happy, so will guide you to the correct join syntax.  And it will also include the aliases with the field names in your joins.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if it's confused over which instance of tbl_EQUITYMapping to join against.

I'd expect to see your from block look a little more like this:

```
select *
FROM tbl_EQUITYINPUT a
LEFT JOIN tbl_EQUITYMapping b
ON a.FundCode = b.SchemeCode_Client
LEFT JOIN tbl_EQUITYMapping c
ON a.Ticker = c.SecurityCode_Client
LEFT JOIN tbl_EQUITYMapping d
ON a.Broker = d.Brokercode_Client
```

In this case, you are joining three different copies of tbl_EQUITYMapping with tbl_EQUITYINPUT. But I don't think that is what you want to do. If you are pulling data from tbl_EQUITYMapping, the select won't know which copy to pull it from.

I expect that SchemeCode_Client, SecurityCode_Client, and Brokercode_Client form a composite key for tbl_EQUITYMapping. In which case I would expect a from block that looked like this.

```
select *
FROM tbl_EQUITYINPUT a
LEFT JOIN tbl_EQUITYMapping b
ON (a.FundCode = b.SchemeCode_Client 
        AND a.Ticker = b.SecurityCode_Client
        AND a.Broker = B.Brokercode_Client)
```

In this case, you'd get only one copy of tbl_EQUITYMapping

You could equally well do something like this:

```
select *
from tbl_EQUITYINPUT a, 
        tbl_EQUITYMapping b
where 
    (a.FundCode = b.SchemeCode_Client 
        AND a.Ticker = b.SecurityCode_Client
        AND a.Broker = B.Brokercode_Client)
```

(the designer may or may not optimise that for you in the former version)

Comment: i want your first query to be executed. It works very well in sql server. but same thing is not working in ms access. I am newbie to ms access.

Comment: That should work on either. Did you notice I added the a., b., c., and d.'s to the from clauses?

Comment: when field name are different a , b, c are of no use. we can directly use the field name.